# Derivation of an integral function in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

I know that for any continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(y)dy = f(x).$$
Let's say that $f\in L^p$ for $p>1$. Can I say that the equality still holds almost everywhere?
If not, what is the largest subset of $L^p$ such that the equality holds almost everywhere?

Comment: This is true for any integrable function. It is called Lebesgue's differentiation Theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: Ok, many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Lebesgue's differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), this is true for all $f \in L^1$. As $L^p([0,1]) \subset L^1([0,1])$, your conjecture holds.